# error: 'int' object is not iterable in Python

Tags: python

look at the error message ,everything i can't find the error ,we insert the value into function trip_cost('Los Angeles', 4) , and city will be string and days will be int 
type ,is that any knowledge i should know?

## code:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140*nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):    
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
    else :
        return 123

def rental_car_cost(days):
    total = days *40
    if days >=7:
        total=total-50
        return total
    elif days >= 3 :

        total=total-20
        return total
    else :
        return total
def prev_add(a,b):
    return sum(a,b)
def trip_cost(city,days):
    nights = days
    hotel_cost_price = hotel_cost(nights)
    rental_car_price=rental_car_cost(days)
    prev_price = prev_add(rental_car_price,hotel_cost_price)
    plane_ride_price = plane_ride_cost(city)
    return sum(prev_price,plane_ride_price)
```

========================

## error code :

```
 trip_cost('Los Angeles', 4) raised an error: 'int' object is not iterable
```

===================

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you writing/running this in? I remember one of my students giving me an error like yours and I was really confused because there wasn't a traceback showing where the error was at all levels (not just the top-most, e.g. `trip_cost` call). I really hate the "friendly" interfaces that hide crucial detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) computes the sum of an iterable, such as a list. However, you are trying to use it to add two numbers:

```
def prev_add(a,b):
    return sum(a,b)
```

If you want to simply add `a` and `b`, use `+`:

```
def prev_add(a,b):
    return a + b
```

In this case, I would get rid of the function altogether and just use addition.

The same goes for your use of `sum()` in

```
return sum(prev_price,plane_ride_price)
```

Comment: would you also like to suggest `def prev_add(*nunbers): return sum(numbers)`,

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Interesting suggestion, thanks. However, I feel it's much too advanced for this question (and in this case doesn't really add anything over the simple use of `+`).

Comment: you are correct, few days back I started reading cookbook (an advance course) where I found [this suggestion from there](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=S_SJ2LaZH8EC&pg=PT324&lpg=PT324&dq=def+avg%28first,+*rest%29:&source=bl&ots=Dyd1AodTmT&sig=4pZyUTryQ53GpPB8fKhYTjDd-qs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oNCbVPHYOIixuASYiYLICQ&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=def%20avg(first%2C%20*rest)%3A&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Just check the sum help documentation. sum(3,2) will fail, but sum((3,2)) will work. Since sum(3,2) is considered as sum function called with two parameters passed, while sum((3,2)) is considered as one parameter passed to the sum function.

```
>>> help(sum)
Help on built-in function sum in module __builtin__:

sum(...)
    sum(sequence[, start]) -> value

    Return the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
    of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
    empty, return start.

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler, you don't need the extra `prev_add` function.

The solution is to set your `city` variable (which you pass to `trip_cost`) to the result of `plane_ride_cost(city)` inside `trip_cost`

```
def trip_cost(city, days):
    city = plane_ride_cost(city)
    return city + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days)
```